# How filter one table based on values of another table using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have mapping table "data", first column shows group, second is dummy (whether to use this group from "output" table) and third shows the number of row

[image]

and table that shows the output "output", with columns showing values for each of the group

[image]

I want that the final table looks like

[image]

In my code I tried to select values from 3rd column from "data" table (ploeg2 values in the code) and then use them as an index for column selection in "output" table. However, ploeg2 shows value only for a and b group and do not know how to select necessary columns from "output" and paste it to the sheet.

```
Sub sample()

Dim rng As Range

  Set rng = Range("data")

Dim ploeg As Range
    Dim ploeg2 As Range

    For v = 1 To 5
        If Cells(v, 2) = 1 Then
            Set ploeg = Cells(v, 3)
            If ploeg2 Is Nothing Then
                Set ploeg2 = ploeg
            Else
                Set ploeg2 = Union(ploeg2, ploeg)
            End If
        End If
    Next v
    
 Set tbl = Range("table")
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Resize(ploeg2.Rows.Count, ploeg2.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = ploeg2.Cells.Value

finaltable = tbl.Range(, ploeg2)
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M1") = finaltable

  'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Resize(ploeg2.Rows.Count, ploeg2.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = ploeg2.Cells.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set ploeg = Cells(v, 3)` - don't think is right. If v=1 then cells(v,3)=1 I think whereas you want the cell containing 5 ?

Comment: Yes, the code is not working properly. 5 is for the number of rows in table "data", so I wanted to go through every row for column 2 and if it was =1 then same the same row but from column 3

Comment: Is `rng` the middle table?

Comment: Yes, it is the same as "data" table, it seems that in If condition should be `rng.Cells(v, 2) = 1` , but not sure