# How select values from one column based on values from the another column in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table "data", where I want to save row values in column 3 (shows row number) based on condition if values in column 2 = 1

[image]

The next table shows the information below. I want to filter this table showing only columns a,b,e (1,2,5 column order). The index for columns is retrieved from the first table's 3rd column because the order of the rows is equivalent to the order of columns in the second table.

[image]

I wrote a code, however, it saves only 1 and 2 values (from column 3 ), but the number 5 should be also saved.
How can I change the code to getting the right 3rd column values from the first table and then filter the second table?

```
Dim ploeg As Range
   Dim ploeg2 As Range

   For v = 1 To 5
       If rng.Cells(v, 2) = 1 Then
           Set ploeg = Cells(v, 3)
           If ploeg2 Is Nothing Then
               Set ploeg2 = ploeg
           Else
               Set ploeg2 = Union(ploeg2, ploeg)
           End If
           
       End If
   Next v
   

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Resize(ploeg2.Rows.Count, ploeg2.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = ploeg2.Cells.Value


End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is that ploeg2 will refer to multiple non-contiguous ranges and ploeg2.Cells.Value will only return values from the first range, in this case 1,2.

Comment: But how then I can select the necessary value from the 3 column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the values use an array to 'collect' them.

This code assumes the data is in the range A1:E5.

```vb
Dim ploeg As Range
Dim arrVals()
Dim cnt As Long
dim v As Long

   ReDim arrVals(1 To 1, 1 To 5)

   For v = 1 To 5
       If Cells(v, 2) = 1 Then
           Set ploeg = Cells(v, 3)
           cnt = cnt + 1
           arrVals(1, cnt) = ploeg.Value          
       End If
   Next v
   
   If cnt > 0 Then
       ReDim Preserve arrvals(1 To 1, 1 To cnt)
       Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Resize(cnt).Value = Application.Transpose(arrVals)
   End If
```

Comment: thank you, but is it possible to save them all in one table and then paste to excel sheet rather pasting step by step?

Comment: The code isn't 'pasting' step by step, it uses the same loop as the original code and after it puts the values found directly into column E in one go.

Comment: Good. But can I save Application.Transpose(arrVals) to a table inside VBA to use this table further i.e. `Dim test As Range   test.Value = Application.Transpose(arrVals)` (code does not work properly because do not know how to save it inside macro for further modification.) instead of `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Resize(cnt).Value`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a 'table'. You have all the values you want in the array arrVals and you can refer to that elsewhere in the code. What were you going to do with ploeg2 in the original code?

Comment: in `ploeg2` the logic is following: it joins all rows where `Cells(v, 2) = 1`, for different values of v it collects values from `Cells(v, 3)` using Union command. Shortly, `ploeg2` is all true values for `ploeg`. The main task why I need these numbers is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66854891/how-filter-one-table-based-on-values-of-another-table-using-vba?noredirect=1#comment118177816_66854891

Comment: Could you please edit your original post to clarify exactly what you want to do? The code I posted follows the logic of your original code, the only difference is it will return all the required values.